# Does a treatment X vs. placebo study qualify as a "comparative study"?

Tags: research, terminology, placebo

I wonder whether a study comparing medical treatment with a placebo qualifies as a "comparative study".

Looking at PubMed's MeSH tags, I don't see much consistency:

- http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26350485 is a treatment X vs. placebo randomized controlled trial and *doesn't have* the "comparative study" MeSH tag.
- http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17404192 is a treatment X vs. placebo randomized controlled trial and *has* the "comparative study" MeSH tag.